# Filter dataframe into 3 buckets

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Scala Spark `Dataset`, `ds` and two functions `isTypeA()` and `isTypeB()`, which take rows in that `Dataset` and return whether or not that row should be classified as A or B respectively. They can both return true for the same row, in which case I want to classify that row as A. Finally, I want C to be the rows that are neither `A` or `B`. I would like to save this as 3 separate `Dataset`s.

I can do this by using `filter` and calling the functions multiple times

```scala
val a = ds.filter(isTypeA(_))

val b = ds.filter(row => !isTypeA(row) && isTypeB(row))

val c = ds.filter(row => !isTypeA(row) && !isTypeB(row))
```

but is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: If you specifically want 3 DS assigned distinctively, I don't think you can do much better. An alternative would be `groupBy` and operate on the individual groups or you can `reduce` to a `Tuple3 : (a, b , c)` and then read that data back into individual DS but I don't reckon that will be performant.

Comment: @sinanspd okay, thanks. My other idea was to create tuples `(isA, isB, row)` and then have 3 `flatMap`s with a `case` statement, but I don't know if moving the tuple around would be more expensive than just running the `isTypeA`/`isTypeB` more than once.